# Escape String in Grails to avoid JSON error

Tags: java, json, grails, unicode-escapes, stringescapeutils

I have few strings like

```
"12.10 On-Going Submission of ""Made Up"" Samples."

10. PRODUCT STANDARDS; APPROVAL.
```

which I render as JSON in grails. The quotes and any other possible special characters are giving me trouble i.e they make the JSON invalid when returning a response from the REST service. How do I solve this? I have tried few things but nothing seems to work:

```
//text: java.net.URLEncoder.encode(artifact.text, "UTF-8"), //Loses the original format
//text : artifact.text.encodeAsJavaScript(), // give problem with ;
//text: artifact.text.encodeAsHTML(),       // gives &qoute(not wanted) in the text instead of "
//text: StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava((String)artifact.text), //some error
// text : artifact.text   // the json gets cut at the string
```

I have a similar question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26025673/json-issues-with-rest-api-and-special-characters) to give you the idea of what exactly I am facing
The code snippet :

```
def index() {

    def document
    def artifacts
    def documentId
    def documentName
    def artifactType
    def artifactStatus
    def includeClassifications
    def classifications
    def mapOfAtifactTypes = [:]
    def listOfArtifacts = []
    def listOfClassifications = []
    def rtnVal = [:]

    documentId = params.documentId
    documentName = params.documentName

    try {

        if (! rtnVal?.msg ) {
            //if we dont' have a message yet it means we don't yet have a failure so we can continue

            if (document){
                rtnVal.documentName = document.docName
                if (artifactType) {
                    artifacts = Artifact.findAllByDocumentAndArtifactType(document, artifactType)
                }
                else {
                    artifacts = Artifact.findAllByDocument(document)
                }
            } else {
                artifacts = Artifact.list();
            }

            if (artifacts) {   
                    def artifactToAdd = [
                            documentId: artifact.documentId,
                            documentName: artifact.document.docName,
                            artifactId: artifact.id,
                            //URLEncode so slashes and other control characters don't cause the rendered JSON to truncate
                            //TODO look up the proper way to encode text prior to JSON rendering
                            //text: java.net.URLEncoder.encode(artifact.text, "UTF-8"),
                            //text : artifact.text.encodeAsJavaScript(),
                            //text: artifact.text.encodeAsHTML(),           
                            //text: StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava((String)artifact.text),    
                            text: artifact.text.replace("\"","\\\""),           
                            status: artifact.status ?: Artifact.ArtifactStatus.FOR_REVIEW.value,
                            hasClassification: listOfClassifications ? true : false
                    ];

                    listOfArtifacts.add(artifactToAdd)
                    }
                rtnVal.listOfArtifacts = []
                mapOfAtifactTypes.each { entry ->
                    rtnVal.listOfArtifacts.add([
                            type: entry.key,
                            artifacts: entry.value
                            ])
                }


        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        rtnVal = [
                status: "Bad request",
                msg: e
        ]
        render e
    }

    render rtnVal as JSON
}
```

Comment: Are you inside of a controller ? If so, what's the problem with `render yourObject as JSON` ? It should escape the strings properly.

Comment: it does but the string get converted to  %2212.10+On-Going+Submission+of+%22%22Made+Up%22%22+Samples.%22
Reviewed :

Comment: @Javier92 the json is not complete, it stops at "text":"\"12.10 On-Going Submission of\"\"" when not encoded

Comment: Mmmh I never faced that kind of problem. And what about the simple Groovy converter ? `new JsonObject(yourObject).toPrettyString()` ?

Comment: I am not using Gson library .never used it before

Comment: I'm a little confused tbch. Could you show us at least some code snippet of your object, how you instanciate it (with the strings that are causing you trouble), where you convert it to JSON and where you return it to the client ?