# Escaping double Quotes in String

Tags: java, grails, escaping, html-escape-characters

How do i escape double quotes in string in Grails :

```
string  = " "12.10 On-Going Submission of ""Made Up"" Samples." "
```

I have tried alot of methods

```
//text : artifact.text.encodeAsJavaScript(),
//text: artifact.text.encodeAsHTML(),           
//text: StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava((String)artifact.text), //got an error when doing this     
//text: artifact.text.replaceAll("\" "," \\\\" "),
```

None of the above worked for me. You can refer to question posted by for understanding myproblem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26025673/json-issues-with-rest-api-and-special-characters)
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26039819/escape-string-in-grails-to-avoid-json-error) too

the error (json stops at "\\"12.10 On-Going Submission o\\"\\""):

```
014-09-25 12:15:21,869 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - StringIndexOutOfBoundsException occurred when processing request: [GET] /artifact - parameters:
documentName: ICENSE AGREEMENT6
String index out of range: -28. Stacktrace follows:
Message: String index out of range: -28
    Line | Method
->> 1911 | substring      in java.lang.String
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1946 | subSequence    in     ''
|   1042 | append . . . . in java.io.PrintWriter
|     56 | append         in     ''
|    180 | value . . . .  in grails.converters.JSON
|    162 | convertAnother in     ''
|    202 | value . . . .  in     ''
|    162 | convertAnother in     ''
|    202 | value . . . .  in     ''
|    162 | convertAnother in     ''
|    202 | value . . . .  in     ''
|    162 | convertAnother in     ''
|    202 | value . . . .  in     ''
|    162 | convertAnother in     ''
|    202 | value . . . .  in     ''
|    134 | render         in     ''
|    150 | render . . . . in     ''
|    325 | $tt__index     in com.thomsonreuters.ald.aeandsdx.ArtifactController$$EOqtIczI
|    198 | doFilter . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter       in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run            in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: Why not this work `"12.10 On-Going Submission of \"\"Made Up\"\" Samples."` ???

Comment: What was the problem about StringEscapeUtils? What did it return?

Comment: @MichałUrbaniak it gave me an error of missing property exception

Comment: Can you publish a code sample with the stacktrace?

Comment: Well the property exception was due to the library being not there.  I added the library but it stopped at "\\\"12.10 On-Going Submission o\\\"\\\""

Comment: How about `string  = ' "12.10 On-Going Submission of ""Made Up"" Samples." '`

Comment: what should i use from the above  ?

Comment: Instead of escaping the double quotes, you can use single quotes. See http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1525-Strings

Comment: I get the text from some lets say black box. So i just have to kind of process it as is