# StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava Error Cannot escape double quotes

Tags: java, json, grails, utf-8, escaping

I have a string which looks like:

```
text = " "12.10 On-Going Submission of ""Made Up"" Samples." "
```

I am trying to escape the double quotes. I have tried the following thing:

```
import groovy.json.StringEscapeUtils;
textFinal: escapeJava(text)
```

BTW this text is going to be a JSON response. I am getting the following error as JSON response

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.thomsonreuters.ald.aeandsdx.ArtifactController.escapeJava() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: ["12.10 On-Going Submission of ""Made Up"" Samples."]{"status":"Bad request","msg":{"arguments":["\"12.10 On-Going Submission of\"\"
```

on the console I am getting this error :

```
2014-09-25 14:55:07,555 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - StringIndexOutOfBoundsException occurred when processing request: [GET] /artifact - parameters:
documentName: ICENSE AGREEMENT6
String index out of range: -25. Stacktrace follows:
Message: String index out of range: -25
    Line | Method
->> 1911 | substring      in java.lang.String
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1946 | subSequence    in     ''
|   1042 | append . . . . in java.io.PrintWriter
|     56 | append         in     ''
|    180 | value . . . .  in grails.converters.JSON
|    162 | convertAnother in     ''
|    202 | value . . . .  in     ''
|    162 | convertAnother in     ''
|    202 | value . . . .  in     ''
|    162 | convertAnother in     ''
|    202 | value . . . .  in     ''
|    134 | render         in     ''
|    150 | render . . . . in     ''
|    328 | $tt__index     in com.thomsonreuters.ald.aeandsdx.ArtifactController
|    198 | doFilter . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter       in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run            in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

Don't know why this wont work. This should. To get more clear picture what exactly I am trying to do refer [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041797/escaping-double-quotes-in-string)  [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26039819/escape-string-in-grails-to-avoid-json-error) and 
 [Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26025673/json-issues-with-rest-api-and-special-characters)

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're just importing `StringEscapeUtils` in a regular way, but then you're not explicitly calling the method from the right class.

I suspect you either want:

```
import static groovy.json.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava;
textFinal: escapeJava(text)
```

or:

```
import groovy.json.StringEscapeUtils;
textFinal: StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(text)
```

Comment: I did the latter one but my JSON go truncated {
"documentName":"ICENSE AGREEMENT6",
"listOfArtifacts":[
{
"type":"Clause",
"artifacts":[
{
"documentId":6951,
"documentName":"ICENSE AGREEMENT6",
"artifactId":7029,
"text":"\\\"12.10 On-Going Submission o\\\"\\\""

Comment: @krs: That sounds like it's probably either just your logging, or your input being truncated. I very much doubt that it's got anything to do with the escaping part.

Comment: When you say input being truncated, i do get an string index out of   bound error on the console too.

Comment: ok i got you.. what you say is correct. i did get the esacping right. I jsut printed the text and its perfect. \"12.10 On-Going Submission of \"\"Made Up\"\" Samples.\". But why is the JSON getting truncated

Comment: @krs: I have no way of knowing that, but it sounds like a different question, and one that you should ask in a different post.

Comment: is it because i render it again as JSON at the end ?

Comment: @krs: I can't possibly tell, because all I've got is those two lines of code. But again, that's off the topic of this question. *Please* take the hint and start a new question with all the relevant details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047623/json-get-truncated-in-rest-service-possible-because-of-double-quotes